# Why is converting a float to String with additional split faster than just converting to int?

Tags: python, benchmarking

Answering a question about how to remove the float part of a number (remove .25 from 100.25), one user answered that `int(float_num)` was a good way to remove it's float part. I came across a way using strings that I thought was obviously worse than that, but I thought it was interesting to consider it. This was my answer: `str(float_num).split('.')[0]`. Longer and uglier, this approach seems worse than just converting to int.

Then, could anyone explain me why the benchmarks I tried, gave better results to the longer method than to the simpler? Maybe having a core i7 computer affects the results? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: The final answer's type doesn't need to be an int. The point is just analyze why removing the float part is faster with the str method (in my case)

[image: benchmarks]

Comment: You aren't converting to an integer. It's still a string

Comment: then how do i need to benchmark it, please do not downvote, i'm just learning!

Comment: timeit.timeit('int(str(100.25).split(".")[0])', number = 100000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because in the `str` case you're not benchmarking the conversion, because you didn't put them as a string to be executed. Rather, the Python interpreter will execute the "conversion" before giving the result (which is "100") into `timeit`, which will happily "execute" the statement (which is basically doing nothing).

Putting the statement to be run in quotes, increases the time by order of magnitude, showing the actual running time:

```
>>>timeit.timeit('str(100.25).split(".")[0]', number = 100000)
0.0971575294301
>>>timeit.timeit(str(100.25).split(".")[0], number = 100000)
0.00131594451899
```

Referring to my comment - the type conversion to int is where the time is going:

```
>>>timeit.timeit('int(str(100.25).split(".")[0])', number = 100000)
0.14871997597698083
>>> timeit.timeit(str(100.25).split(".")[0], number = 100000)
0.0013893059552003706
>>> timeit.timeit('int(100.25)', number = 100000)
0.019588643801725425
```

And as your number gets longer, the string method will get slower quicker than the integer method. They grow at different rates.

Comment: I think that i didn't explain well. The answer doesn't need to be a int. I just provided a string method and the other person a (let's say) int method. In the end both methods remove the float part.

Comment: So the first 'timeit' doesn't match with the case I am trying to explain

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the result. If you just want to print it, then leaving it as a string is fine. If you want to do math with it you will end up having to convert it to a number.

Comment: Let's just think about the fastest method. you have a float number and someone tells you to remove the float part, regardless the following steps. Why the longest (str) method is faster?

Comment: I just realized from your edit, that actually OP is doing the benchmarking wrongly. By not quoting the `str(100.25).split(".")[0]`, OP is not benchmarking the conversion, but it's just reading the string "100", which is basically doing nothing, so that's why it's faster. @sihrc: can you change your answer to make this point the main point? Because that's exactly where the mistake

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple string manipulation is faster than a type conversion, even if it is simply float to int you are still casting it as a new type.

The String manipulation however is just chopping off part of what it already has, no complexity or maths involved.

Comment: but you have a float number from the beginning, and I do a str(float_num)

Comment: I see, your question is then: "Why converting to String (even with additional split) is faster than converting to int?"

Comment: keeping in mind, as the # of digits you have increases, the result you get is different. Strings grow at different rates

Comment: -1. String manipulation isn't necessarily cheap, and type conversion isn't necessarily expensive. A type cast from float to int can AFAIK be done with some bit masking. And since Python can use native types for both (usually C long for ints and IEEE doubles for floats), it is just possible that could be done *in processor*. The string split, on the other hand, needs to involve a *linear search*. "no complexity or maths involved" - computers are *good* at maths. It is *very* surprising that converting between two native numeric types should appear to take longer than a linear search.

Comment: It was one opinion of a possible cause